# ¿De dónde viene el significado de "gamba" como "crustáceo"?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

En los primeros tiempos del español, la palabra *gamba* tenía el mismo significado que tiene hoy día en italiano: "pierna".

> *Mas por la vermina que es dentro eillos se vntan los braços & las gambas de jus 
>   de limones & dotras yerbas.*
>
> Anónimo, "Viaje de Juan de Mandevilla", c 1400 (España).

Esta palabra, que Covarrubias decía que era un vocablo italiano que solo conocían los que habían salido de España, ya estaba marcada como "de poco uso" por el *Diccionario de Autoridades*. De hecho, se encuentran muy pocos casos en el CORDE.

El uso de *gamba* como "pierna" se mantiene en el diccionario durante mucho tiempo, y no es hasta 1936 cuando por fin aparece la acepción referente al crustáceo, ya prácticamente igual a [la actual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IoEUloK):

> 1. f. Crustáceo semejante al langostino, pero algo menor, y sin los surcos que tiene aquel en el caparazón a uno y otro lado de la quilla mocha. Habita en el Mediterráneo y es comestible.

Con esta acepción, el primer caso del CORDE es de unos años antes, de finales del siglo XIX:

> *Los percebes, las gambas, las ostras escabechadas, las cañaillas, los langostinos y los camarones son los más usados como ordubres.*
>
> Ángel Muro, "El Practicón. Tratado completo de cocina", 1891-1894 (España).

Sin embargo, lo que no sé es cómo se originó esta acepción de *gamba* como "crustáceo". Mirando la etimología de la palabra, veo:

> Del it. *gamba* 'pierna', este del lat. vulg. *camba* 'pierna de las caballerías', y este del gr. *καμπή kampḗ* 'curvatura'.

Dado que en última instancia viene de una palabra griega que significa "curvatura", ¿podría ser que el origen de esta acepción sea porque la gamba es un animal con el cuerpo curvado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No deriva del italiano *gamba* ("pierna") sino del latín *cammarus* ("langostino").

CAMMARUS pasó a GAMBARUS, y de ahí al catalán GAMBA. En español usamos desde el siglo XX la palabra catalana, sinónimo de la castiza *camarón*.

Puede ser (aunque no veo referencias válidas), que efectivamente gamba/pierna y gamba/crustáceo estén emparentados en el indoeuropeo **kamer*, "curvatura", de donde viene *cámara*.

Comment: ¡Qué bueno! El diccionario catalán [dice](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0068483): _1416; probablemente extraído del plural anterior_ gàmbers, _pronunciado_ gambes, _latín vulgar_ cambărus, _latín culto_ cammărus, _y este, del griego_ kámmaros, _seguramente cruzado con el griego_ kárabos _'bogavante'_.

Comment: Así que al final las dos acepciones tenían etimologías diferentes. Acabo de escribir una propuesta a la RAE (usando [el formulario](http://www.rae.es/formulario/unidrae) que tienen para ello) solicitando que las dos acepciones, al tener orígenes y etimologías diferentes, estén en entradas diferentes ("gamba1" y "gamba2"). ¡Gracias por la información!